# Why a new value of this property get assigned after the POST request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

When a new `InvoiceItem` is created, its `InvoiceItemId` is generated. For some reason, whenever I call `OnPost` page handler in `EditInvoiceModel`, the ids of my items in `InputModel` get generated again.

### InvoiceItem

```
public class InvoiceItem
    {
        public string InvoiceItemId { get; set; }
       
        
        public InvoiceItem()
        {
            InvoiceItemId = GenerateID.GenerateItemID();
        }

    }
}
```

### EditInvoiceModel

```
public class EditInvoiceModel : PageModel
    {

        public readonly InvoiceService _service;

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string InvoiceId { get; set; }

        public EditInvoiceModel(InvoiceService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        
        public async void OnGet(string id)
        {
            Invoice invoice = await _service.GetInvoice(id);
            Input = new InputModel();

            Input.Items = invoice.Items; 

        }

        public  async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string id)
        {
           if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.EditInvoice(Input, id);
                return RedirectToPage("/ViewInvoice", new { id = id });
            }

            return Page();
        }

    }
```

### CreateInvoiceModel

```
public class CreateInvoiceModel : PageModel
    {
        
        public readonly InvoiceService _service;

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public CreateInvoiceModel(InvoiceService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }


        public void OnGet()
        {
            Input = new InputModel();
            Input.PopulateItems();
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.AddInvoice(Input);
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }

            return Page();

        }

    }
```

### My Input Model

```
 public class InputModel
    {

        public List<InvoiceItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<InvoiceItem>(16);


        public void PopulateItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Capacity; i++)
            {
                Items.Add(new InvoiceItem());
            }
        }
    }
```

### EditInvoice Service

```
public async void EditInvoice(InputModel input, string id)
        {
            var invoice = await _context.Invoices.Include(x => x.Client).Include(x => x.Items).FirstAsync(x => x.InvoiceId == id);

            if (invoice == null) { throw new Exception("Unable to find the invoice"); }
            

            invoice.Items = input.Items;

            

            invoice.Description = input.Description;
            invoice.InvoiceDate = input.InvoiceDate;
            invoice.PaymentTerms = input.PaymentTerms;
            invoice.Client = input.Client;
            

            invoice.BillFromAddress = input.BillFromAddress;
            invoice.BillFromCity = input.BillFromCity;
            invoice.BillFromCountry = input.BillFromCountry;
            invoice.BillFromPostal = input.BillFromPostal;
            _context.Entry(invoice).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: How's your `RedirectToPage("/ViewInvoice"` looks like? Could you please share along with the full `controller` code

Comment: looks like your doing that with a constructor in InvoiceItem class: InvoiceItemId = GenerateID.GenerateItemID();  (seems like you'd want the database to set the primary key instead on creation.)

Comment: @pcalkins How would I do that in EF Core ?

Comment: Can you share the code for EditInvoice?

Comment: @JasonPan I just did.

Comment: Can you set breakpoint in this line `invoice.Items = input.Items;` in your EditInvoice? Pls check the InvoiceItemId whether being changed ?

Comment: @user18012137 the model should just be the structure of the data... keep the UID as null (don't set it) when creating the record ex: _context.table.Add(modelItem)  and it should generate one for you.  Should be public int ID...

Comment: Seems like you'd need more properties for the invoiceitem class.  Why only an ID?